# php regex match a comma delimited list of integers

Tags: php, regex

I know the following regex will match a single integer, as well as a list of comma delimited integers:

`/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/`

How can i turn this into only matching a *list* of integers? A single integer should **not** match. `123,456` and `634,34643,3424` should match.

Comment: Like this `/^\d+(?:,\d+)+$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `+` operator meaning "one or more" times instead of `*` to repeat your group.

```
/^\d+(?:,\d+)+$/
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nU5rI2/2)